# Placeholder settings for a simple neural network

Tags: tensorflow, placeholder, logistic-regression

My data is the following CVS file:

```
1,0
2,0
3,0
4,0
5,1
6,0
7,1
8,1
9,1
10,1
```

I want to perform logistic regression on this with the first column as x and the second column as y. Furthermore, I want to do this using TensorFlow with a simple neural network consisting of a single input node and a single output node (no hidden layer). As I am using only 1 node for input and 1 node for output, do I use

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1]) 
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])
```

?

I am not interested at this stage with using batches because I want to understand the other parts first.

Comment: Are you asking if you only need the two placeholders you listed?

Comment: Have you tried? Any error or issue with placeholders? Basically, if you don't care for batches at this point, a more straightforward instruction for both `x` and `y` is `tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1])`. Also, you may change floats for integers.

Answer (score 0):

I see where you are confused about (if you know how logistic regression works).
1. For this single-dimension logistic regression setting, you just need `tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1])`, as @Eric mentioned.
2. If a placeholder is set to have shape `[None, dim]`, it means the data batch size is not decided when constructing network (corresponds to the first one being `None`), and that data has a dimension of `dim`.
3. Note that in Tensorflow convention, batch size usually comes out first. You'll see how convenient it is -- no transpose needed if you construct multiple layers of `Wx+b` networks.